# Is $-a^2+2ta-1$ and $-b^2+2tb-1$ are also coprime for any positive integer $t>a$ and $t>b$

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $a,b$ be two coprime positive integers. I am asking if $-a^2+2ta-1$ and $-b^2+2tb-1$ are also coprime for any positive integer $t>a$ and $t>b$.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think they are coprime? Have you looked at several small cases?

Comment: @CalvinLin: I have no idea to start.

Comment: Run a spreadsheet for $ a, b $ coprime up to 10 (or 20) and t up to 20 (or 30). Are all of those coprime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous counter examples even for small values. Just go find one.

---

Rewrite the expression as $\gcd(2(t-1)a - (a-1)^2 , 2(t-1)b -(b-1)^2)$.

Does this immediately suggest how we could make the GCD (a multiple of) 2?

> E.g.  $a, b$ odd coprime numbers, $t$ anything, then clearly both terms are even.

Comment: But it is not true that both terms are even.

Comment: @Safwane I agree that it's not true that both terms are even **always**. Is it ever true that both terms are even? Note that your question is "are these always coprime", so a valid answer is "No, these are not always coprime. here are some instances that they are not coprime".

Answer (score 0):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[GCD[a, b] == 1 && 
     GCD[2*t*a - a^2 - 1, 2*t*b - b^2 - 1] == 1 && t > a && 
     t > b], {a, b, t}, Nothing], {a, 2, 10}, {b, 2, 10}, {t, 2, 
   10}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={{{{2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 3, 9}}, {{2, 5, 
    6}, {2, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 9}, {2, 5, 10}}, {{2, 7, 8}, {2, 7, 
    9}}}, {{{3, 2, 4}, {3, 2, 6}, {3, 2, 7}, {3, 2, 8}, {3, 2, 
    9}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 8}, {3, 4, 
    10}}, {{3, 8, 9}}}, {{{4, 3, 5}, {4, 3, 6}, {4, 3, 7}, {4, 3, 
    8}, {4, 3, 10}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 7}, {4, 5, 8}, {4, 5, 9}, {4, 
    5, 10}}, {{4, 7, 8}, {4, 7, 9}}}, {{{5, 2, 6}, {5, 2, 7}, {5, 2, 
    9}, {5, 2, 10}}, {{5, 4, 6}, {5, 4, 7}, {5, 4, 8}, {5, 4, 9}, {5, 
    4, 10}}, {{5, 6, 7}, {5, 6, 8}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}, {{5, 8, 
    9}, {5, 8, 10}}}, {{{6, 5, 7}, {6, 5, 8}, {6, 5, 9}, {6, 5, 
    10}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {6, 7, 9}, {6, 7, 10}}}, {{{7, 2, 8}, {7, 2, 
    9}}, {{7, 4, 8}, {7, 4, 9}}, {{7, 6, 8}, {7, 6, 9}, {7, 6, 
    10}}, {{7, 8, 9}}}, {{{8, 3, 9}}, {{8, 5, 9}, {8, 5, 10}}, {{8, 7,
     9}}, {{8, 9, 10}}}, {{{9, 8, 10}}}}
```

So, we can see that you're right!

Comment: Can you check your code? You used `GCD[2*t*a - 1, `. It should be $2ta - a^2 - 1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin done!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "see that you're right"? OP is asking for "for any positive integers ...", whereas your script seems to show that there there are counterexamples. E.g. $a = 3, b = 5, t = $anything doesn't appear, as I stated in my solution.